# Is it possible to abstract the stream map into a method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, java-stream

I know this question might be weird, but I found that I've been using stream and then map standardly on lists in my program and I thought that it's kinda long and I was thinking if it's actually possible to refactor that into an easily callable short method that would look like

```
public List<?> getStreamMap(List<?> list, String attribute)
```

Which would be the equivalent of this:

```
list.stream().map(e->e.getAttribute).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know this question might be weird, but I found that I've been
> using stream and then map standardly on lists in my program and I
> thought that it's kinda long and I was thinking if it's actually
> possible to refactor that into an easily callable short method that
> would look like
>
> public List getStreamMap(List list, String attribute)

You were not that off, you needed to pass the lambda as a parameter i.e., the functional interface [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), namely:

```
 public <T> List<?> method(List <T> list, Function<T, ?> attribute){
        return list.stream().map(attribute).collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```